# Mailcore 2 can not access gmail messages except Inbox folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail-imap, mailcore

With Mailcore 2 I am able to access Yahoo's almost all folders' messages but when I try for gmail , it can only access Inbox folder messages. Please anyone know whats going wrong.

This is my code

```
if ([dict count] > 0)
            {
            myAccountsession = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
            [myAccountsession setHostname:[dict objectForKey:@"incomingserver"]];
            [myAccountsession setPort:993];
            [myAccountsession setUsername:[dict objectForKey:@"email"]];
            [myAccountsession setPassword:[dict objectForKey:@"password"]];
            [myAccountsession setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];
            }
 MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = (MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind)
        (MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindStructure |
         MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindInternalDate | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaderSubject |
         MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags);
        NSString *folder = foldernamestring;
        NSLog(@"foldername to fetch mails %@",folder);
        MCOIMAPFolderInfoOperation *inboxFolderInfo = [myAccountsession folderInfoOperation:foldernamestring];

        [inboxFolderInfo start:^(NSError *error, MCOIMAPFolderInfo *info)
         {
        //access messages in folder..
         }];
```

Comment: solved . https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/303

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right operation to retrieve a list of messages. The operation that you are using (MCOIMAPFolderInfoOperation) just retrieve metadata information for the folder specified. Instead of this operation, you should be using MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation, this operation will give you a list of message for a specific folder. More description of this operation can be found here (http://libmailcore.com/mailcore2/api/Classes/MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation.html).

An example how to retrieve the messages with this operation would be:

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
[session setHostname:@"imap.gmail.com"];
[session setPort:993];
[session setUsername:@"ADDRESS@gmail.com"];
[session setPassword:@"123456"];
[session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];

MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders;
NSString *folder = @"INBOX";
MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];

MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:folder requestKind:requestKind uids:uids];

[fetchOperation start:^(NSError * error, NSArray * fetchedMessages, MCOIndexSet * vanishedMessages) {
    //We've finished downloading the messages!

    //Let's check if there was an error:
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error downloading message headers:%@", error);
    }

    //And, let's print out the messages...
    NSLog(@"The post man delivereth:%@", fetchedMessages);
}];
```

Comment: i figured it out, it was because i was sending just folder name but to retrieve messages you have to provide path. ex.with [Gmail]